# Prove that if $\Delta p$ is zero, then $\hat{p}\psi=\bar{p}\psi$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, wavefunction

**This is a question from my homework assignment from Harris' "Modern Physics", p.193.**

It first asks to prove that $$(\Delta p)^2 = \int_{all \hspace{.3mm} space} \psi^*(x)(\hat{p}-p)^2\psi(x)dx$$
I could solve this part from the derived definition of the standard deviation I've learned:
$$ (\Delta p)^2 =  \bar{p^2} - \bar{p}^2$$ Then with some math I managed to get the first expression. Next, the question asks to show that:
$$ (\Delta p)^2 = \int_{all \hspace{.3mm} space} \left[(\hat{p}-p)\psi(x)\right]^*\left[(\hat{p}-p)\psi(x)\right]dx $$
The question gives two hints;  $\bar{p} $ is real, and it suggests using integration by parts to derive the second expression. The question then asks to show that if the uncertainty is to be zero, then $\hat{p}\psi$ must equal $\bar{p}\psi$ which isn't an issue.

This is where I'm encountering some problems. When I integrate by parts twice by choosing what I felt were the suitable functions, I get the following result (naturally, I would get non-integral functions):
$$ (\Delta p)^2 = \int_{all \hspace{.3mm} space} \left[(\hat{p}-p)\psi(x)\right]^*\left[(\hat{p}-p)\psi(x)\right]dx \hspace{1mm} + (i\hbar)\left[ \psi^*(x)\left( i\hbar \frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x} + \bar{p}\psi(x) \right) \right]_{all \hspace{.3mm} space}$$

So now my question is: Is there a physical or mathematical reason for me to say that the term on the right has to be zero? Since that is the only way I can have the integral alone equal $(\Delta p)^2$. If you think I've gone in a wrong direction from the start, please direct me with a hint or two.

Comment: Your second (surface) term is at infinity, where all wave functions are assumed to vanish.